# Use a custom UITableViewCell for many UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` for a `UITableView` by dragging and dropping the labels and `imageView` from my Prototype Cell to a Custom Cell which I call QuizInfoCell.

That works fine for the particular `TableView` that I created the Prototype Cell in, but I can't get `QuizInfoCell` to work for any other `TableView.` How can I achieve that?

This is the code that I'm using in the `TableView` that created the Prototype Cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    QuizInfoCell *cell = nil;       
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"QuizInfoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[QuizInfoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"QuizInfoCell"];
    }

    cell.name.text = [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.author.text = [author objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.time.text = [[ValueHandler alloc] getDateString:[timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.plays.text = [@"Plays: " stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [plays objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]]];
    cell.ratingUps.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [ratingUps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.ratingDowns.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [ratingDowns objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.qid.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [qid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: :What error you got. Then show your custom cell class

Comment: depending where you created the item you can need to load it in different manors. did you create it in a storyboard or in a xib?

Comment: I created it in the storyboard. The h file for the Cell only contained the labels. I didn't change the m file at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating your `QuizInfoCell` as a new XIB file.

- Press CMD + N
- Select the `User Interface` submenu.
- Create a new `View` and call it `QuizInfoCell`

In your new XIB delete the existing View element and instead drag and drop a new `Table View Cell`.

Recreate your custom `UITableViewCell` in the same way as you did before by dragging and dropping the labels and imageView

Finally give the new Cell an Identifier called `QuizInfoCell`, like this:

[image]

You can then load your new Custom UITableViewCell with Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    QuizInfoCell *cell = nil;       
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"QuizInfoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"QuizInfoCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.name.text = [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.author.text = [author objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.time.text = [[ValueHandler alloc] getDateString:[timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.plays.text = [@"Plays: " stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [plays objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]]];
    cell.ratingUps.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [ratingUps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.ratingDowns.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [ratingDowns objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.qid.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [qid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I'm on the brink of getting what I desire. But now when I run this I get the following error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier QuizInfoCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Do you know why that happens?

Comment: I guess it's because you need to give the new Cell an Identifier called QuizInfoCell. I have updated my answer to illustrate how to do so.